# How to setup bloom to generate a local deb, outside of ros.org buildfarm

Tags: ros, catkin, deb, bloom-release, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
This question is related to this one: http://answers.ros.org/question/173804/generate-deb-from-ros-package/

Basically, what we need to do is to provide our ros packages to project partners and clients.
But we do not want to distribute the source code for some of the nodes (some yes, and some no).
And we don’t want either to appear yet in the official ROS buildfarm/jenkins/repo for project confidentiality required by some clients.
And we will want in the future to add obfuscation of python code and license management for C++ code with LMX for example...

So we’ve been digging around the ROS release process.
But things are not really clear to us yet.

Would you know how to do, or how would you advise us to do in order to generate such installers so that our clients can easily install it and that we can check release numbers, and send only compiled code.
I think there are 2 ways:

1. The “easier” but not sure if it works well: generate a tar.gz of the catkin workspace after having cleaned it from source code…. Do you have experience on this? Do we need to remove the devel folder? if we remove the src folder this doesn't work, do we  need to leave at least the config and lanch files? more?... Is this documented somewhere? Maybe we need to compile catkin with release flag?
2. The more complex but cleaner and more long-term: generating a debian and putting it on a server.
   I’ve seen that we can use Bloom to generate a debian automatically in GitHub. And then there is pull generated to populate the ROS buildfarm…

- But then, where is it compiled? In local? By github? By ros.org?
- How can we specify/include in the debian only compiled code and not source code? (or a mix)
- Can we generate only one debian for a metapackage? or will we have to generate as many .debs as packages?
- Do you know how to disable this pull to ros.org? and to github (or how to configure the deb to be generated on our git server?)
- If we don’t publish it on ros.org, can we still get the track feature to manage release version and tags etc…
- If/when we'll have generated the .deb, what kind of server would we need to implement to get a private server to be able to run apt-get? (or any similar method) Might PPA be the solution? Or can one call an apt-get on a private git server since the release debian will be there?

3. And finally, how/where does the obfuscation popsup in this process?

Thanks in advance for any advice and guidelines.
You will have understood that we know more or less what we want, but have little idea of the available options and how to implement this... what a program :-)

For the question point 2, for a first package that in particular defines its own services, we started to follow some steps found here http://answers.ros.org/question/173804/generate-deb-from-ros-package/ but without success yet...

We do run `bloom-generate rosdebian --os-name ubuntu --os-version precise --ros-distro hydro` without error in the prompt.
But when running `fakeroot debian/rules binary` the compiler doesn’t find the include files that are located in the "devel/include/" directory of the catkin workspace and thus aborts.
Those header files are auto-generated by catkin_make when defining services in my main code... Any idea on to solve this?
Also, could you elaborate on the 2 alternatives you are proposing: checkinstall and dpkg-buildpackage ? Thanks in advance.

Thanks in advance

Damien

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192419/how-to-setup-bloom-to-generate-a-local-deb,-outside-of-ros.org-buildfarm/) by [Damien](https://answers.ros.org/users/2349/damien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 203 on 2014-09-10

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-09-12**:
@Damien I haven't forgotten about this, I'm at ROSCon right now, so it might be a few days before I get to this. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll see if I can address your questions and then give a suggested approach:

> The “easier” but not sure if it works well: generate a tar.gz of the catkin workspace after having cleaned it from source code…. Do you have experience on this? Do we need to remove the devel folder? if we remove the src folder this doesn't work, do we need to leave at least the config and lanch files? more?... Is this documented somewhere? Maybe we need to compile catkin with release flag?

When you build a catkin workspace, you can tell it to do `make install`. This can be done with `catkin_make install` or `catkin_make_isolated --install`, depending on the build tool you are using. The result will be an `install` folder along side your `src`, `build`, and `devel` folders. This `install` folder stands on its own, you can delete the `src`, `build`, and `devel` folders and it will still function. It is also relocatable (a feature that cross-compiler's frequently use), meaning you can move the folder and it should still work. Debian package generation does just this, it takes the result of bloom (source + debian configuration files) and builds then installs your packages into an `install` folder, then it packages up that install folder and that is what is distributed in the resulting `.deb` file.

> The more complex but cleaner and more long-term: generating a debian and putting it on a server. I’ve seen that we can use Bloom to generate a debian automatically in GitHub. And then there is pull generated to populate the ROS buildfarm…

The `bloom-release` command will generate the required debian configuration files, and then open a pull request on github. The pull request is only required if you are going to have our build farm compile your packages into `.deb` files. This requires that your code is open source, so this will not be what you want. As @IsaacSaito suggested, this answer should help you manually build the `.deb` from the result of bloom without a pull request or our farm:

http://answers.ros.org/question/67345/build-debian-package-locally/?answer=67373#post-id-67373

Then you can automate that process with a CI server like Jenkins or buildbot, see `buildbot-ros`:

https://github.com/mikeferguson/buildbot-ros

> But then, where is it compiled? In local? By github? By ros.org?

If you open the pull request it will be built on jenkins.ros.org and the result hosted on packages.ros.org (open source only).

> How can we specify/include in the debian only compiled code and not source code? (or a mix)

If you are using our farm, the source code and binaries are both always provided in the result, there is no configuration, hence the requirement for open source.

> Can we generate only one debian for a metapackage? or will we have to generate as many .debs as packages?

If you are using bloom, there will be one `.deb` per package and per metapackage (contains just the metapackage not the packages which belong to it). If you want to generate a single `.deb` for multiple catkin packages, consider combining `catkin_make install` (which is really just `cmake` + `make` + `make install`) with `checkinstall`:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall

> Do you know how to disable this pull to ros.org? and to github (or how to configure the deb to be generated on our git server?)

The answer linked above tells you how to use bloom to generate the debian configurations, but not open a pull request.

> If we don’t publish it on ros.org , can we still get the track feature to manage release version and tags etc…

No, all of our tools require our infrastructure, but they are all open source and designed with as few assumptions about infrastructure as possible, so it would be possible to adapt them to private use, though at this time we do not provide documentation on how to do that.

> If/when we'll have generated the .deb, what kind of server would we need to implement to get a private server to be able to run apt-get? (or any similar method) Might PPA be the solution? Or can one call an apt-get on a private git server since the release debian will be there?

To host `.debs` you will need an apt repository:

https://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository

> And finally, how/where does the obfuscation popsup in this process?

We don't support this functionality at all, this is entirely up to the user, we provide our process and infrastructure to facilitate federated collaboration, so it isn't a feature which is requested often enough for us to support.

> But when running fakeroot debian/rules binary the compiler doesn’t find the include files that are located in the "devel/include/" directory of the catkin workspace and thus aborts.

So the fake_root process assumes that you have your dependencies available for what ever package your are trying to build, you likely did not source the `setup.bash` file for the workspace containing the packages on which your package is depending.

Hopefully this gives you some directions in which to go investigating solutions. If you find something that works really well for your use case please consider providing details here for others.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Damien](https://answers.ros.org/users/2349/damien/) on 2014-09-16**:
Thanks a lot William.
We'll need a bit of time to digest all this and find our way to generate our packages.
The buildbot-ros seems a good option...  the checkinstall to generate a single deb also...

**Comment by [Damien](https://answers.ros.org/users/2349/damien/) on 2014-09-18**:
William, I've came up to the conclusion that I first need to get `catkin_make install` produce the `/install` correctly.
So, Can I/Should I/Where (adding a /install/src?) should I add the source code of a restricted number of my nodes to my future deb? ROS is only hosting it in github, right?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-09-18**:
I don't understand your comment. You don't need source code to ship the install space. If you want to include source code I would do it separately. ROS is not hosting anything on your behalf, if your code is on github it is because you put it there. I think I am just mis understanding the question.

**Comment by [Damien](https://answers.ros.org/users/2349/damien/) on 2014-09-18**:
Goal is to ship a complete product to a client, with binary, docs and some source code. I dont want ros.org to host anything. But not sure about how to ship these src examples... So I though to config Cmakelist to generate in /install both binaries and copy source files; get deb with FPM and ship

**Comment by [Damien](https://answers.ros.org/users/2349/damien/) on 2014-09-18**:
I referred to ROS just as a reference: in opt/ros there is no source code but the equivalent of \install. Apart, you provide source in github for us to compile.
My option might be to make install, clean my catkin_ws folder from build devel and some src pckg, then get a FPM deb or a targz to ship.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-09-18**:
If your customers can use Debian packages, provide them with both source and binary packages.

**Comment by [Damien](https://answers.ros.org/users/2349/damien/) on 2014-09-18**:
@joq any hint on how to generate a source debian for ros? Bloom will only generate a binary package I think. no?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-09-18**:
The build farm uses the bloom git build package to generate source packages for each target, then uses them to generate the binaries. I don't know the details, but the information is all there.

**Comment by [Damien](https://answers.ros.org/users/2349/damien/) on 2014-09-23**:
Hi again. I'm going step by step...
To comply git-buildpackage I've setup a github server for my source and release
Now I want to run `bloom-release --rosdistro hydro --track hydro repository_name` but I'm not sure about what to do to make sure that no Pull request is sent to ROS
Can you explicit?

**Comment by [Damien](https://answers.ros.org/users/2349/damien/) on 2014-09-23**:
Or maybe I should run `bloom-generate rosdebian --os-name ubuntu --os-version precise --ros-distro hydro` instead?
I really don't want to mix up with Ros official build farm....